# Number of lines on a weak del Pezzo surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, fano-varieties

By a line I mean a (-1)-curve. Given a weak del Pezzo surface $X$ of degree $d$, how many lines would $X$ contain?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? This depends of course on the configuration of $(-2)$-curves on $X$. A case by case analysis is not difficult but tedious.

Comment: @abx I was hoping that the number of lines would be the same as for del pezzos of degree $d$, but this might of been too optimistic of me. How would you determine the number of lines depending on the configuration of $(-2)$-curves?

Comment: Let me give an example: the blowing up of 6 points on $\mathbb{P}^2$. If the points are general, you get the (in)famous 27 lines: the 6 exceptional divisors and the strict transforms of the 15 lines through two of the points and of the 5 conics through 5 of the points. But if your points lie on a smooth conic, the latter disappear and you have only 21 lines.

Comment: @abx I understand! So this would be the case of a weak del pezzo of degree 3 with a single minus $(-2)$-curves (ie it is the minimal desingularisation of a cubic surface with an $A_1$ singularity)? Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: H U: Yes, exactly.